# Paper.js function to create ZigZag line inside key binding returning 'nan'

Tags: paperjs

I have a function to draw a ZigZag line, thank you @sasensi, which is called inside a onKeyDown event. For some reason it is returning `nan` when creating the normal.

[codpen](https://codepen.io/limitedunlimited/pen/ExgMzVy?editors=0010)

Comment: Could you try to provide us a code that reproduce the issue, without the need for user interaction ? For example, capture your function input when the issue is arising and hard code it to reproduce the issue. We could better help you this way.

Comment: Given that I am using mouse events, should I be using event.count and event.delta rather than getPointAt and getNormalAt to create the zigzag?